# Как называется речевой оборот/стилистическая фигура?

Tags: стилистика, стили-речи, фигуры-речи

Подобный речевой оборот достаточно часто встречается в стихах.

Суть в том, что вместо дублирования слова, например:

> Просыпайся, солнце — солнце уже встало.

В предложении уходят от дублирования, используя это слово единожды, при этом, по смыслу, оно относится и к первой части предложения и ко второй.

> Просыпайся солнце уже встало.

При этом, в письме можно явно показать к какой части предложения это слово относится, расставив знаки препинания, но при устном произнесении должно быть ясно, что слово относится к обоим частям предложения.

*Возможно, приведен не самый лучший пример.*

Comment: Следите за метками, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aer, Спасибо за исправление, но метка «синтаксис» здесь неуместна.

Comment: Я так не думаю, ведь ваш вопрос о синтаксисе. Речь идет о слове, как бы одновременно выполняющем две разные синтаксические функции. А метки типа _фигуры-речи_ крайне неопределенны. Что вы вкладываете в них? О стилях речи в вашем вопросе ни слова. Вы говорите в лучшем случае о жанре.

Answer (score 2):

Мне не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете в виду.

Первое предложение: *Просыпайся, солнце — солнце уже встало.*
Правильная пунктуация должна быть такой: Просыпайся, солнце, солнце уже встало.
Или такой (с паузой): Просыпайся, солнце, — солнце уже встало.
В любом случае первое "солнце" нуждается в выделении запятыми, потому что это обращение (его можно изъять из предложения).

Второе предложение: *Просыпайся солнце уже встало.*
Здесь одиночное "солнце" является членом предложения, пунктуация такая:
Просыпайся, солнце уже встало.
Нельзя написать "Просыпайся, солнце, уже встало", потому что при удалении обращения предложение теряет смысл. (Просыпайся уже встало.)

Возможно, чтобы не повторяться, заменить второе "солнце" безличным глаголом:
**Просыпайся, солнце, уже светает**.
**Просыпайся, солнце, уже рассвело.**

[**Светать**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1017890/%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC), **светает**, безл., несовер. О восходе солнца: рассветать.

[**Рассвести**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1003238), рассветёт (рассвенёт обл., прош. вр. **рассвело**, безл., совер. (к рассветать). О рассвете: начаться, появиться. *Уже рассвело, когда мы проснулись.*

*— Григорий, вставай, светает*! (М. Шолохов. Тихий Дон)
*— Просыпайся, рассвело, в путь пора* (А. Буцайло. Мастер по нечисти).

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, я тоже не поняла, о каком обороте идёт речь. Под словом ОБОРОТ Вы имели в виду стилистическую фигуру?  На пропуске слова или сочетания основано довольно много фигур речи, но ни одна из них не похожа на Ваш пример.

Если смысл фразы зависит от пунктуации, может, Вы имели в виду пунктуационную **амфиболию**?

Это разнообразные вариации типа "Казнить нельзя помиловать","Варить нельзя выкидывать", "Поставить статую золотую пику держащую".

Есть ещё стилистическая фигура ЗЕВГМА, когда  в результате **аппликации** - наложения двух словосочетаний друг на друга ** происходит совмещение в опорном слове двух разных значений и возникает семантическая контрастность (антитеза) между компонентами сочинительного ряда.** Эта фигура  помогает создать «смешной», комический эффект: *Этот скандал, несмотря на свою видимую ничтожность, обошёлся ему очень дорого. Благодаря ему он **потерял** свою новую форменную фуражку и веру в человечество (А.П. Чехов).* Слово **потерял** относится **и к вере, и к человечеству**, совместив два значения - потерять конкретный предмет и потерять абстрактное понятие ( лишиться веры).

Comment: Не представляю как это нагляднее описать. Суть такова, что говорится: «Просыпайся, солнце уже встало», при этом подразумевается: «Просыпайся, солнце, солнце уже встало». Я не раз встречал такую стилистическую фигуру в творчестве современных поэтов, широко известных в узких кругах. Делается это, как я понимаю, для сохранения рифмы без потери смысла. К сожалению, сейчас не смогу найти реальный пример.